# Run Azure Function via Powershell command

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-durable-functions

Is there a way to run Azure Function using PowerShell command?

[image]

Start-AzFunctionApp -Name "function-name" -ResourceGroupName "resource-group-name" this starts the function but I don't see any command for running the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this command

**POST-method:`Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri <function url>` to execute the Http Trigger in my function app.**

**For GET-method: `Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri <function url>`**

I have created a python function with function name **`HttpTrigger1`**, ran the PowerShell command to execute the function.

[image]

[image]

I have used default sample code for HTTP trigger. My code.

**`__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Run PowerShell command `Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri <function url>`

**`Output`:**

I have used `?name=Vivek` to pass the value for `name`.

[image]

**EDIT:**

`Get Method`: `Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri <function url>`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I get this error Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found on running Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri "<function url>"

Comment: @user989988 try using `get` method `Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri https://<function-app-anme>.azurewebsites.net/api/<functionname>`.
[image](https://i.imgur.com/TYvrpzh.png)

Comment: @user989988 URL does not support POST method it is throwing `404` error. Use `Get` method command.

Comment: Here is my url: https://<function-app-anme>.azurewebsites.net/api/StarterFunction?code=xyz

Comment: @user989988 did you try using get method?

Comment: If possible please share the full URL. you need to share `<function-app-name>`. 
As you can see My function app name is `pyfunc` and function is `HttpTrigger1`.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $functionUrl worked however I see it returning a big html response. Is there a way to get the status that is running?

Comment: @user989988 it will return the response after the process is `completed` with message which is set in the `func.HttpResponse`.

Comment: What permission is required to run Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $functionUrl? I have Microsoft.Web/sites/* permission however I see 401 (Unauthorized)